# Why aren't my graph points being displayed? (Java graphing problem)

Tags: java, math, graphing

I'm new to java with one class under my belt so far.
This is a recreational program I'm working on, if you imagine a window where each x and y coordinate correspond to the base integers in a times-table and each product is a pixel, each pixel has a corresponding value from multiplying their coordinates. So the pixel at (4,9) has a value of 36.
What I want the program to do is use an array to compare the products of the coordinates (x * y) to a list of prime numbers (P), if the product is one less than a prime then draw a dot. My code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;

public class PrimeAdjacents extends Canvas {
    static int screenSize = 500;
    int[] integersX = new int[screenSize];//all integers along the X axis
    int[] integersY = new int[screenSize];//all integers along the Y axis
    //this list of prime numbers came from GitHub, all primes up to 1500
    int[] prime = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113,
            127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257,
            263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409,
            419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571,
            577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733,
            739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907,
            911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061,
            1063, 1069, 1087, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1109, 1117, 1123, 1129, 1151, 1153, 1163, 1171, 1181, 1187, 1193, 1201, 1213,
            1217, 1223, 1229, 1231, 1237, 1249, 1259, 1277, 1279, 1283, 1289, 1291, 1297, 1301, 1303, 1307, 1319, 1321, 1327, 1361,
            1367, 1373, 1381, 1399, 1409, 1423, 1427, 1429, 1433, 1439, 1447, 1451, 1453, 1459, 1471, 1481, 1483, 1487, 1489, 1493,
            1499};


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creates the screen
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PrimeAdjacents"); //give screen a name
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        PrimeAdjacents canvas = new PrimeAdjacents();
        // Sets the size of the screen
        // See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html
        canvas.setSize(screenSize, screenSize);
        // Sets the background color
        // See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html
        canvas.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }

    /*if the product of any x coord and any y coord is equal to any prime-1
    then draw a red dot at that coordinate,
    if the product is not adjacent to a prime then draw a blue dot
     */
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < integersX.length; i++) {
            int ex = integersX[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < integersY.length; j++) {
                int wy = integersY[i];
                for (int k = 0; k < prime.length; k++) {
                    int P = prime[k];
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    g.fillOval(P, P, 5, 5);//draw dots at each prime-squared
                    if (ex * wy == P - 1) {
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g.fillOval(ex, wy, 5, 5);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that I've provided a list of prime numbers up to 1500 to compare against. The comparison is happening in the paint method and I have it drawing dots at P-squared just to show that the graphics are working, but the points at P-1 either aren't being drawn or only the first one is being drawn. I'm using IntelliJ in case that's important.
Can anyone tell what I need or need to change to get the points I'm looking for?

[Current program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etI8u.jpg)

[Times Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wJZ9.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You iterate the coordinates of the canvas with `i` and `j`, but you never used these values for anything except to pull zeroes out of your two arrays that are filled with zeros from when you first instantiated them. So `ex * wy` will always be zero and nothing will be drawn since `1` isn't in your primes array.

You don't need the `integersX` and `integersY` arrays, since you can use `i` and `j` directly as your coordinates.

```
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < screenSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < screenSize; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < prime.length; k++) {
                    int P = prime[k];
                    if (i * j == P - 1) {
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g.fillOval(i, j, 5, 5);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey that worked, thank you! 
Can you elaborate a little? I thought I was assigning ex and wy as each value in the array in sequence, do those variable values not iterate with the array?

Answer (score 0):

I reworked your code to use a drawing `JPanel` rather than a `Canvas`.

Here's the GUI I came up with.  It took about 2 seconds on my super desktop to calculate the prime numbers and draw the dots.  It may take longer on your system.

[image: Prime Adjacent GUI]

Here are the major changes I made.

1. All Java Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that all Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. I used a drawing `JPanel` rather than a `Canvas`.
3. I calculated all the primes up to width / 5 times height / 5.  I divided by 5 because each dot you're drawing takes up 5 pixels.  So, a 500 x 500 drawing area can show 100 x 100 dots.
4. In the `paintComponent` method of the drawing JPanel, I moved as much code as I could outside of the triple for loops.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PrimeAdjacentGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PrimeAdjacentGUI());
    }
    
    private final int drawingPanelWidth;
    private final int drawingPanelHeight;
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private PrimeNumbers primeNumbers;
    
    public PrimeAdjacentGUI() {
        this.drawingPanelWidth = 500;
        this.drawingPanelHeight = 500;
        this.primeNumbers = new PrimeNumbers(
                drawingPanelWidth, drawingPanelHeight);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Prime Adjacent GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(drawingPanelWidth, 
                drawingPanelHeight);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private final int width;
        private final int height;
        
        public DrawingPanel(int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            List<Integer> primes = primeNumbers.getPrimeNumbers();

            for (int i = 0; i < width / 5; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < height / 5; j++) {
                    int product = i * j;
                    for (int k = 0; k < primes.size(); k++) {
                        int prime = primes.get(k);
                        if (product == (prime - 1)) {
                            g.fillOval(i * 5, j * 5, 5, 5);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class PrimeNumbers {
        
        private final List<Integer> primeNumbers;
        
        public PrimeNumbers(int width, int height) {
            this.primeNumbers = calculatePrimeNumbers(
                    width, height);
        }
        
        private List<Integer> calculatePrimeNumbers(
                int width, int height) {
            List<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
            primeNumbers.add(2);
            primeNumbers.add(3);
            
            for (int i = 5; i < width / 5 * height / 5; i += 2) {
                boolean isPrime = true;
                for (Integer prime : primeNumbers) {
                    if (i % prime == 0) {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                if (isPrime) {
                    primeNumbers.add(i);
                }
            }
            
            return primeNumbers;
        }

        public List<Integer> getPrimeNumbers() {
            return primeNumbers;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a little beyond me so I'll be studying it. Can the JPanel help with making the graph zoom/resizable?

Comment: @lastbrunneng: You'll need to explain what you mean by zoom / resizable.  You'll have to repaint the JPanel with different dot sizes to create the illusion of zoom.